# Calling a Static Method In Main

Tags: java, methods, static, rational-number

How do call the last method on this class, in main? I am just trying to return a new Rational object that contains the product of the two parameters. Every time I try to call it in main, I can't use integer in the parameters, since it only accepts objects. So how do I multiply two number if it only accepts objects. (I can't change the parameters to integers, it's part of a problem set). Your help will be appreciated. Here my code:

```
 public class Rational {
        private int numer, denom;


        public Rational(int numer, int denom){
            this.numer = numer;
            this.denom = denom;


        }

        public Rational(Rational rational){
            rational = new Rational(numer, denom);


        }

        public void setNumber(int fum){
            numer = fum;
        }

        public int getNumber(){
            return numer;
        }

        public void setDenom(int Dum){
            denom = Dum;
        }

        public int getDenom(){
            return denom;
        }

        public Rational reciprocal(){
            System.out.println(denom + "/" + numer);
            return new Rational(denom, numer);
        }

        public static Rational multiply(Rational a, Rational b){
            int bar = a.numer;
            int bla = b.denom;
            int multi = bar * bla;
            System.out.println(multi);
            return new Rational(bar,bla);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just create two `Rational` objects and pass them as arguments?

Comment: But wouldn't that have 4 parameters in total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rational rational1 = new Rational(1,2);
        Rational rational2 = new Rational(1,2);
        Rational result = Rational.multiply(rational1, rational2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Also, do you have any tips in respect to improving this code?

Comment: @userb No problem, and for getting advice on improving the code I recommend posting a separate question on codereview.stackexchange.com